# How to execute an event in real time

Tags: python, qt

I'm trying to use qt to run a function in real-time, but qt works so that when you call a function, the answer comes only when the function is executed. How do I make it so that when you call a function and an event occurs in it, I can stop and wait for some event before moving on.

P / s I'm really sorry for my English. I hope you understand me.

Comment: The question makes not much sense. For the real time you need not Qt which is GUI framework on any OS but Real Time OS and some API to program it. You were understood: no sorries.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, the solution may be as simple as calling the second event at the end of the first. Alternatively, your problem may require signals and slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are, generally, and always in C/C++, atomic computational units. That is, once they are called, they can't be *paused*, however, you can pause threads of execution. So, a *possible* workaround to what you want could be to execute your function in its own thread and pause it, but once you pause it you can't resume it from the function since it's paused. You would need some sort of *controller* for pausing and resuming functions, you will inevitably end up coding a *thread scheduler* more or less like what operating systems have.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to do something about it.